# When default shell is not bash-compatible, why do bash scripts not work well?

Tags: bash, shell-script, fish, chsh

My default shell is fish, because it's a lot nicer.  But often when I run scripts, I get errors that seem to be from the bash script being processed by fish.  I think this is because the script writer assumed that the default shell is bash, but I don't understand the mechanism.

For instance, the CrashPlan install.sh script starts with a bash shebang:

```
~/CrashPlan-install> head install.sh
#!/bin/bash

#############################################################
# Linux Client Installer Script
#############################################################
```

So when I run `./install.sh` it should be processed by bash, right?  The default terminal shell should be irrelevant.  Yet, when my default shell is fish, running scripts like this causes fish to return errors, as if it's processing the script:

```
fish: Expected a command name, got token of type “Run job in background”. Did you mean
 “COMMAND; and COMMAND”? See the help section for the “and” builtin command by typing “help and”.
Standard input: sed -imod "s|Exec=.*|Exec=/usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanDesktop|" 
 /home/username/Desktop/CrashPlan.desktop && rm -rf /home/username/Desktop/CrashPlan.desktopmod
```

Is this because of a misconfiguration of my computer or because the script is written in a non-portable way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So when I run `./install.sh` it should be processed by bash, right?

Indeed. That's exactly what the shebang is for.

#### Troubleshooting

- Save the following as `test.sh` and try to run it from fish.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  true && true
  ```

  It works on my computer, and it should on yours.
- Check if the first line of `install.sh` contains only the characters `#!/bin/bash`.

  Invisible characters (such as a CR linebreak) could confuse fish.
- Run

  ```
  /bin/bash --version
  ```

  to check that bash is actually bash and hasn't been accidentially replaced/modified over time.

#### install.sh

`$SRC_USER` is just a synonym the script creates for `$SUDO_USER`.

As a result, when the script is run with root privileges, the command

```
su ${SRC_USER} -c "sed -imod \"s|Exec=.*|Exec=${GUISCRIPT}|\" ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER} && rm -rf ${DESKTOP_LAUNCHER}mod"
```

automatically uses the sudo user's default shell, which is fish.

To override this default, add the instruction `-s /bin/bash` to the `su` command.

Comment: `./test.sh` runs fine, produces no errors, and a hex dump of test.sh and install.sh is identical for the first 13 bytes. And yes, it's `GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release`. Something to do with the `Exec=` part of the install.sh script?

Comment: Maybe, but it's hard to tell out of context. Could you post `install.sh` here or, if it's too long, on Pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xAZM1BgF  Oh no, now I see the "Exec" is part of a `.desktop` file that the script creates, not part of the script itself.

Comment: I honestly don't get it: fish can't handle any of the if commands, so why wait until the sed line to choke? What happens if you run `bash install.sh`?

Comment: the same thing happened with `sudo install.sh` or `bash install.sh`.  Something to do with `su ${SRC_USER}`?  But root's default shell is bash.

Comment: I think you got it. `su`  executes the command using `SRC_USER`'s shell, which, if I got it right, is precisely not `root`. Try replacing `su` with `su -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the `su` command. I've created a user `fishy` with fish as its default shell. From bash, `su fishy "true && true"` results in an error. `su fishy -s /bin/bash -c "true && true"` works fine.

Comment: awesome, that seems to fix it.  can you put that in your answer before I accept it?

Comment: Glad for it. I've updated my answer.